# Using R SOAP (SSOAP) to retrieve data / scrape

Tags: python, r, soap, rcurl

On the B-cycle page(www.bcycle.com/whowantsitmore.aspx) I am trying to scrape locations and values of votes.

The URL http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx is a SOAP service.

Based on the [documentation](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/SSOAP/html/genSOAPClientInterface.html) I believe I am doing it correctly but I get an error due to parsing the input parameters. Even calling a function without parameters also creates errors.

```
# working with SOAP
#install.packages("SSOAP", repos="http://www.omegahat.org/R", dependencies = T, type =  "source")
library(SSOAP)

# Process the Web Service Definition Language (WSDL) file
bcycle.asmx <- processWSDL("http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx?WSDL")

# Generate functions based on definitions to access the different data sets
bcycle.interface <- genSOAPClientInterface(bcycle.asmx@operations[[1]], def = bcycle.asmx, bcycle.asmx@name, verbose=T)

# Get the data by requesting the number of cities, username and password (yes it is public)
bcycle.interface@functions$getCities("10","bcycle","c@rbont0ns")
# receive error: Error in as(parameters, "limit.userName.pw") :
# no method or default for coercing "character" to "limit.userName.pw"
```

This is due to the following code in the function:

```
function(parameters = list(...),... etc) {
    ...
    as(parameters, "limit.userName.pw")
    ...
}
```

I have therefore tried to use the .SOAP function directly:

```
# Using RCurl library
library(RCurl)

# set up curl options
curl.opts <- curlOptions(
    verbose=T,
    header=T,
    cookie="ASP.NET_SessionId=dv25ws551nquoezqwq3iu545;__utma=27517231.373920809.1357910914.1357910914.1357912862.2;__utmc=27517231;__utmz=27517231.1357910914.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);__utmb=27517231.13.10.1357912862",
    httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"),
    followLocation = TRUE,
    useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0")

# Define header and submit request
bcycle.server <- SOAPServer("http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx")
.SOAP(bcycle.server,
    "getCities",
    limit=250,userName="bCycle",pw="c@rbont0ns",
    action="http://bcycle.com/getCities",
    xmlns="http://bcycle.com/",
    .opts=curl.opts,
    .literal=T,
    nameSpaces = "1.2",
    elementFormQualified = T,
    .returnNodeName = 'getCitiesResponse',
    .soapHeader = NULL)
```

I manage to connect to their server but receive the error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
  Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
  http://bcycle.com/getCities#getCities
```

These are the options I have tried to date without success.

Using Python I was able to make the request for getCities but received nothing back.

```
import suds

client = suds.client.Client('http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx?WSDL')

print client # prints WSDL info
print client.service.getCities(10,'bcycle','c@rbont0ns') #prints nothing
```

I'm really interested in keeping this R focused but using python may provide easier insight into what the problem may be.

Any ideas?

Comment: The http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx?WSDL service appears to be unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try correcting username and explicitly naming parameters:

```
library(SSOAP)
bcycle.asmx <- processWSDL("http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx?WSDL")
bcycle.interface <- genSOAPClientInterface(bcycle.asmx@operations[[1]],
                               def = bcycle.asmx, bcycle.asmx@name, verbose=T)
out <- bcycle.interface@functions$getCities(
                     limit="10",userName="bCycle",pw="c@rbont0ns")

#> out[[1]]@
#out[[1]]@zip               out[[1]]@state_name
#out[[1]]@pop               out[[1]]@latitude
#out[[1]]@ambassador_count  out[[1]]@longitude
#out[[1]]@city_name         

out[[1]]@city_name
#[1] "toledo"
```

Python call will also work with the corrected username

```
import suds

client = suds.client.Client('http://mapservices.bcycle.com/bcycleservice.asmx?WSDL')
client.service.getCities(10,'bCycle','c@rbont0ns')
(ArrayOfCities){
   Cities[] = 
      (Cities){
         zip = "43606"
         pop = 337362
         ambassador_count = 455261
         city_name = "toledo"
         state_name = "oh"
         latitude = 41.6743
         longitude = -83.6029
      },............
```

Comment: Spot on. You've got it. Surprisingly using the correct password helps ;) The parameter names were required as well as you suggested. Thanks!