# retrieving SOAP webservices in R

Tags: r, web-services, web-scraping, soap, wsdl

I want to retrieve some data from https://ws01.cenace.gob.mx:8081/WSDownLoadFac/FacturaCENService.svc?singleWsdl
So far, I´ve got the following lines:

```
library(SSOAP)

wsdl <- getURL("https://ws01.cenace.gob.mx:8081/WSDownLoadFac/FacturaCENService.svc?singleWsdl", 
               useragent="R", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
doc = xmlParse(wsdl, asText = TRUE)
def <- processWSDL(doc, verbose = TRUE)
ff  <- genSOAPClientInterface(operations =  def@operations[[1]], def = def, name = def@name,
                              verbose = TRUE)
```

In order to be able to access `ff@functions`, which would be the next step according to [Using R SOAP (SSOAP) to retrieve data / scrape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319462/using-r-soap-ssoap-to-retrieve-data-scrap) a message pop ups asking for some parameters which in fact, I've to enter, such as user.password.date.system.participant:

```
<defClass> usuario.password.fecha.sistema.participante 
defining class usuario.password.fecha.sistema.participante 
Error in (function (object, Class, strict = TRUE, ext = possibleExtends(thisClass,  : 
  no method or default for coercing “character” to “dateTime”
Removing  usuario.password.fecha.sistema.participante from pending
```

Any suggestion of how can I define this values? I tried using

```
pred.Sparams=new(usuario.password.fecha.sistema.participante, usuario="some_user", password="some_password", etc)
```

But that doesnt seems to work.